# Problem Loading swf on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash, html

I have the following swf loaded from `HTML` tag and i do not use swfobject.On Google chrome i see that only after mouse click on the html page the swf file shows up.Any one knows why or what am i doing wrong here

```
<div>
<object id="myMovieName" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
<param value="movie.swf" name="movie">
<param value="high" name="quality">
<param value="#FFFFFF" name="bgcolor">
<embed align=""
   type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
   name="myMovieName"
   bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
   quality="high"
   src="movie1.swf"
   href="movie1.swf">
</object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried takeing the **embed** node out of the **object** node?

It would look like:

```
<object id="myMovieName" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
   <param value="movie.swf" name="movie">
   <param value="high" name="quality">
   <param value="#FFFFFF" name="bgcolor">
</object>
<embed align=""
   type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
   name="myMovieName"
   bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
   quality="high"
   src="movie1.swf"
   href="movie1.swf"/>
```

Thats because OBJECT node doesn't have a EMBED child node in HTML DTD, most browsers can deal with it, but apparently chrome is not one of them, but I'm guessing here.

Comment: Having Google choke myself on a .swf, I was wondering if this issue had been solved with this answer? Will try the suggested approach myself and repost my results I guess.